# Unity Web Request Wrapper

Tags: c#, web-services, unity-game-engine, wrapper

I'm trying to make my own JSON Web Request Wrapper on top of [UWR](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html), so it is easier to debug and change all Network requests from one script instead of debugging and changing on each scene

But I don't know how to return a `string` from a coroutine, can anyone lend me a hand?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

namespace Test
{
    public class JSONUtils : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string GetJSON(string uri)
        {
            // How to return a string from RequestJSON?
            StartCoroutine(RequestJSON(uri));
        }

        private IEnumerator RequestJSON(string url)
        {
            using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
            {
                yield return www.SendWebRequest();

                if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
                {
                    Debug.Log(www.error);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return www.downloadHandler.text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use this other wrapper => https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I don't know how to return a string from a coroutine, can anyone
>   lend me a hand?

Don't make the function return anything. Just make it a `void` function and use the parameter to return the data. Also don't just return only the body of the request. It makes sense to return important debugging information like `isNetworkError`, `isHttpError`, and the `error` of the request string` otherwise you won't know when the request fail or the cause of the failure.

You can do this with [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) or `delegate` but I will use `delegate` in this example because it's allows you to name the callack parameters.

For example, this what it looks like when `delegate` is used:

```
public delegate void ReqCallback(bool isNetworkError, bool isHttpError, string error, string body);
```

And what it looks like with `Action`:

```
public Action<bool, bool, string, string> ReqCallback;
```

Delegate is more descriptive in this case. Just use it as the parameter then call that delegate when the request is done.

Your `JSONUtils` script:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class JSONUtils : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public delegate void ReqCallback(bool isNetworkError, bool isHttpError, string error, string body);

        public void GetJSON(string uri, ReqCallback callback)
        {
            // How to return a string from RequestJSON?
            StartCoroutine(RequestJSON(uri, callback));
        }

        private IEnumerator RequestJSON(string url, ReqCallback callback)
        {
            using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
            {
                //Send request
                yield return www.SendWebRequest();
                //Return result
                callback(www.isNetworkError, www.isHttpError, www.error, www.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
JSONUtils jsonUtils = GetComponent<JSONUtils>();
string url = "yahoo.com";

jsonUtils.GetJSON(url, (isNetworkError, isHttpError, error, body) =>
 {
     Debug.Log("isNetworkError: " + isNetworkError);
     Debug.Log("isHttpError: " + isHttpError);
     Debug.Log("error: " + error);
     Debug.Log("body: " + body);

     if (isNetworkError || isHttpError)
         Debug.Log(error);
     else
         Debug.Log(body);
});
```

You can also move `if (isNetworkError || isHttpError)` into the `JSONUtils` class but I think it is better when placed outside that class. Finally, you can also use a class or struct as the parameter in the `delegate` instead of four different parameter datatypes.

Comment: I didn't knew i could do this.. thank you for showing me